# Getting content of infowindow upon closing it (Google Maps)

Tags: google-maps, infowindow

I'm trying to get the content of a marker's infowindow upon closing it in Google Maps.  The following code works after creating the infowindow:

```
console.log(infowindow.getContent());
```

However, on the close function, I think the infowindow is closed before I can view the content.

```
//Close Infowindow
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow,'closeclick',function(){
    console.log(infowindow.getContent());
});
```

How can I grab the content before the infowindow is completely gone?

Comment: What is changing the content of the infowindow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function () {
  console.log(this.getContent());
});
```

or even

```
infowindow.addListener('closeclick', function () {
  console.log(this.getContent());
});
```

An infowindow's content doesn't change on `closeclick` alone, so you should be able to pull it out with `#getContent` even if it's been closed.